# How to create soap request in ksoap2 for a wcf webservice method with complex types?

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I have successfully accessed web services using ksoap2 but i am stuck with calling a web service method with data contracts.

The webservice request in SoapUI is shown as :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"         
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"   
xmlns:pat="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Patient_Service.App_Code.Common">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:PatientLookups>
     <tem:oPatientDetails>
        <pat:ID>?</pat:ID>
        <pat:Name>?</pat:Name>
        <pat:Age>?</pat:Age>
        <pat:Address>?</pat:Address>
      </tem:oPatientDetails>
   </tem:PatientLookups>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

The arguments ID,Name,Age and Address have different namespaces

Here is the code i used to create the request:

```
request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"PatientLookups");
SoapObject sub_element=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "oPatientDetails");


    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry: properties.entrySet())
        {
            PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setNamespace(entityNameSpace);
            pi.setName(entry.getKey());
            pi.setValue(entry.getValue());

            sub_element.addProperty(pi);

        }
        request.addSoapObject(sub_element);
```

but i get this exception in logcat:

```
 SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:DeserializationFailed' faultstring: 'The formatter threw an 
 exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to  
 deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:oPatientDetails. The 
 InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 411. Element   
 'http://tempuri.org/:oPatientDetails' contains data from a type that 
 maps to the name 'http://tempuri.org/:oPatientDetails'. The deserializer 
 has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a 
 DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'oPatientDetails' 
to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or 
by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see 
InnerException for more details.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:141)
at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:214)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
```

how to create this soap request using ksoap?

Comment: can you post datacontract code of the service and class Patient Details in android.


It looks like its not able to match the andriod patientdetails object to the patientdetails in the service.

You can try changing the default namespace from tempuri to something else, it might work